# MySQL update query where in subquery slow

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-update, subquery, where-in

I'm having issues with MySQL query running extremely slow. It takes about 2 min for each UPDATE to process.

This is the query:

```
   UPDATE msn
   SET is_disable = 1
   WHERE mid IN
   (
       SELECT mid from link
       WHERE rid = ${param.rid}
   );
```

So my question is, I would like to know how the performance of the UPDATE statement will be affected if the result of the subquery is 0 or NULL. Because I think that maybe the process is slow because the result of the subquery is 0 or NULL.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Check out the "multi-table" `UPDATE`.

Comment: @Rick thank you, I'll check it out, and I would like to know is whether the performance of the query will be affected if the result of the subquery is 0 or NULL.

Comment: Is `mid` `NULLable`?  Can it be 0?  These questions apply to both tables.  (That is, there may be 4 combinations of values hidden in your 'simple' question.)  `IN (SELECT ...)` used to perform terribly; what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: NULLable for link table, and Not NULLable for msn table.I'm using mysql 5.7.25. if my subquery result is nothing or no row at all, is that means that WHERE clause in query became like this : WHERE mid = "";?

Comment: Can you provide the execution plan?

Comment: @Ninonino - Let me phrase it differently -- When there are no such rows in `link`, the `SELECT` returns no rows; in this case, the `IN` will fail.  That is, I skipped thinking of it as 0 or null or "", etc.-- just "empty resultset".

Comment: I think I found the problem, I have found that the select type for subquery is dependent subquery. I think thats the reason why its so slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the subquery following `IN` has to execute, whether or not it returns any records.  I would probably express your update using exists logic:

```
UPDATE msn m
SET is_disable = 1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM link l WHERE m.mid = l.mid AND l.rid = ${param.rid});
```

Then, add the following index to the `link` table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON link (mid, rid);
```

You could also try and compare against this version of the index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON link (rid, mid);
```

Comment: Hi Tim! Thank you for the answer. Is there any kind of weird behavior if the subquery result is 0 or NULL?

Comment: The "cost" of the subquery is how long it takes MySQL to assert that it can, or cannot, find a matching `mid` value.  In the worse case, the entire `link` table would have to be scanned (or an equivalent index would need to be scanned).  In the case where the `link` table be completely empty, this lookup would finish very quickly.